# How can I count the number of times any of an array of strings appears in text with Python?

Tags: python, list

I have some text, `raw_text` and I have an array of words:

```
VERBS = ['be', 'am', 'is', 'are', 'was', 'were', 'being', 'been']
```

I want to count the number of times ANY of those words is used in `raw_text`. Case doesn't matter, but word boundaries would.

I'm sure this is doable with Regex or NLTK. Any ideas?

Comment: How big is `raw_text`? If not so large, you can use `Counter(raw_text.split())` then just look at the keys present in `VERBS`

Comment: @DeepSpace Whitespace is not the same as word boundaries though. It wouldn't be that simple

Comment: Check out https://pypi.org/project/gensim/ or any other NLP library. They all support _exactly_ this type of operation straight out of the box.

Comment: This might also be of interest: https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2019/07/how-get-started-nlp-6-unique-ways-perform-tokenization/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
VERBS = ['be', 'am', 'is', 'are', 'was', 'were', 'being', 'been']
raw_text = "This IS example text which we will use to count these words: am, be, is, are"
 

raw_text2 = " " + raw_text.lower() + " "
cnt = 0   
for verb in VERBS:
    cnt += (len(raw_text2.split(f" {verb} "))-1)
    cnt += (len(raw_text2.split(f" {verb},"))-1)
print(cnt)
```